# Alias for an attribute

Tags: java

what is an alias in java? Lets say I have a class with three attributes as shown below and a constructor. how would I Array[] x an alias for the parameter named x, the attribute y an alias for the parameter y, and the attribute z an alias for the parameter z.

```java
public class Apples
  {
    private  Array[] x;
    private String y;
    private String z;






      public Apples(String y, String z, Array[] x)
      {



        }







    }
```

Comment: I don't get what do you want to know. Maybe this will be to help: https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-java-handle-aliasing. Why is your code so wildly formatted? Please format it properly.

Comment: okay yes the code is not formatted well here, but I am following specs and in the specs it says the attribute named x must be an alias for the parameter named x. I do not get what it means by this

Comment: You're asking two questions. What is aliasing is easy to answer. It's having multiple references to same object. The other question about specifications you trying to follow is unclear. What specs do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `z` are [variable shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (or *aliases*) in the *`Apples` constructor*. And you can use `this` to resolve it. Like

```
private  Array[] x;     // <-- attribute named x
private String y;       // <-- attribute named y
private String z;       // <-- attribute named z
public Apples(String y, // <-- parameter named y 
        String z,       // <-- parameter named z 
        Array[] x)      // <-- parameter named x
{
    this.y = y; /* assign parameter y to this instance attribute named y */
    this.z = z; /* assign parameter z to this instance attribute named z */
    this.x = x; /* assign parameter x to this instance attribute named x */
}
```

#### Alias

If your constructor **omitted** `this` like

```
public Apples(String y, String z, Array[] x) {
    y = y;
    z = z;
    x = x;
}
```

You would assign the values back to the parameters (essentially a no-op) because they *alias* the attributes (and the instance fields would be `null`).

Comment: oh okay I am just following specs and it says the attribute named x must be an alias for the parameter named x.

Comment: @hankbb757 Added annotations and a little more explanatory prose. I hope that helps.